# Cannot able to get Location exactly every 10 minutes using Pending Intent and AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-location

I posted my Requirement,Problem and code,I don't know what is wrong with my code,Any help..

**My Requirement :** I want to get latitude,longtitude from GPS every 10 minutes

**Problem :** I am Keep on Getting latitude,longtitude

**My Code :**

**1].I am using this code in activity,I am starting Broadcast Receiver from activity**

```
//Pending Intent
Intent in = new Intent(this,GPSReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, 0);
 //Alaram manager   
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10*60*1000, pi);
```

**2].BroadCast Class "GPSReceiver.class",From here I am starting service names as GPSService**

```
public class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service =  new Intent(context,GPSService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }

}
```

**3].Service Class "GPSService",This is for getting location updates**

```
public class GPSService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    //Flag to know  GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    LocationManager locationmanager;
    String locationgpsprovider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    double latitude;
    double longtitude;

        @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        //To get Location service
        locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //To get GPS Status
        isGPSEnabled = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(locationgpsprovider);
        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your GPS connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {

            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(locationgpsprovider, 0, 0, ll);
            }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("Hei", "10 minutes up");

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longtitude = location.getLongitude();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you noticed if GPSReceiver is being called?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...It is not called,any reason for that?

Comment: Hi,Broadcast is called only once,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Everythime you alarm goes on it delivers another Intent to Service and locationmanager starts all over again. You don't need an Alarm here since LocationManager already deliveries location  at specified intervals.

It's enough starting your Service only once and instantiate your locationmanager stuff at `onCreate`. In this case use `onStartCommand` only to `return START_NOT_STICKY`.

Tip 1: Define a condition to stop the service, don't let it run forever.

Tip 2:Take a look at [requestLocationUpdates javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to setup a proper `minTime`.

Tip 3:You can find more tips in Android docs:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: I want to get location updates exactly every 10 minutes,that is why I am using Pending Intent and alarm manager...Is this wrong way?..If yes,Plz tell me how can i achieve this??